# Как убрать редирект на главную с любой страницы 404

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, редирект

Возникла такая проблема на [сайте](https://riverslot.net/) при вводе любой ссылки которой нету в структуре, например /sdfsdfsdf/ сайт вместо того что бы средиректить на 404.html бросает на главную. Подскажите, пожалуйста как это отключить ? Вот фаил .htaccess В хостинге таких настроек не нашел

```
#AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.riverslot.net$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://riverslot.net/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#ErrorDocument 404 https://riverslot.net


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Редиректы
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
##RewriteRule ^index\.html$ https://riverslot.net/ [R=301,L]
#Redirect 301 /features/index.html /features/
#Redirect 301 /software-versions/index.html /software-versions/
#Redirect 301 /products/river-mobile/index.html /products/river-mobile/
#Redirect 301 /products/river-sweepstakes-system/index.html /products/river-sweepstakes-system/
#Redirect 301 /products/river-redemption-kiosk/index.html /products/river-redemption-kiosk/
#Redirect 301 /products/river-play-at-home/index.html /products/river-play-at-home/
#Redirect 301 /products/river-sweepstakes-gaming-tablet/index.html /products/river-sweepstakes-gaming-tablet/
#Redirect 301 /products/river-stand-up-cyber-cafe-kiosk/index.html /products/river-stand-up-cyber-cafe-kiosk/
#Redirect 301 /products/river-tv-center/index.html /products/river-tv-center/

# Кеширование
<ifModule mod_expires.c>

# Add correct content-type for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff2
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype image/svg+xml

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"

# Cache Images
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 26 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 6 months"

# Cache Fonts
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff2 "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 2592000 seconds"

# Cache other content types (Flash, CSS, JS, HTML, XML)

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"

</ifModule>
```